# Converting back to ndarray from a previous ndarray.tobytes()?

Tags: python, numpy, byte, deserialization

When using numpy, suppose that I have an arbitrary, previously created `ndarray` called `my_ndarray`. I want to be able to do the following, if possible ...

```
my_bytes = my_ndarray.tobytes()
new_ndarray = ## ... somehow convert `my_bytes` back to a `nympy.ndarray`
## ... such that `my_ndarray` and `new_ndarray` are equal
assert(numpy.equal(my_ndarray, new_ndarray)) # I expect this to succeed
```

Is there any way to deserialize something that was ***specifically*** created via `tobytes()` back to a meaningful `ndarray`?

Or am I stuck having to use some other form of serialization/deserialization?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`np.frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html):

```
new_ndarray = np.frombuffer(my_bytes)
```

Demo (python2):

```
>>> x = np.random.randn(10)
>>> my_bytes = x.tobytes()
>>> my_bytes
b'\x8d\x10\xfe\x1e\xaa^\xa0\xbfw\xa26\xca\xbc\xb1\xf5\xbf\x06(C\xe4\x9d\xb9\xae?\xed9\x170rZ\xe9?\x1c\x99\xd5TQ\xbe\xc5\xbfk\xd42\xb3(\xbb\xf3\xbf\xc7K.L\x1fu\xe5\xbfHE\xc2H~\xca\xdd\xbf\xe79\xdfJ\xeec\xf7\xbf\xe3\x9ds\x88\xbe\x1c\xf4\xbf' 
>>> np.frombuffer(my_bytes)
array([-0.03197223, -1.35589293,  0.06000989,  0.79229078, -0.16987054,
       -1.23319311, -0.67054715, -0.46548421, -1.46189718, -1.25701764])
```

Comment: You should be aware of the returned dtype, frombuffer uses float by default, so, this should be changed to match the original array being encoded. Otherwise, you will not get the same result.

Comment: You also need to know the shape. `np.frombuffer(my_bytes, dtype=___).reshape(shape)` is necessary to handle more than 1D arrays.